# How to divide with Big O?

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics

I have to divide this:

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{12k}+\frac{1}{288k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)^2}{1+\frac{1}{12\cdot 2k}+\frac{1}{288\cdot 4k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)}=\left(1+\frac{1}{8k}+\frac{1}{128k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)$$

I know result only thanks by wolfram, but I don't understand it.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%281%2B1%2F%2812k%29%2B1%2F%28288k%5E2%29%29%5E2%29%2F%281%2B1%2F%2812%E2%8B%852k%29%2B1%2F%28288%E2%8B%854k%5E2%29%29%29

I was trying to multiply and divide it by $k^2$ to evaluate this by long division:

$$ \frac{(k^2+12k+288)^2}{k^2+12\cdot2k+288\cdot4} $$

But without good result.

Thanks for advance for any help.

Comment: Since $\frac{(k^2+12k+288)^2}{k^2+24k+1152}\sim k^2\not\sim1$, I take it you've also removed a factor of $k^2$. But it's still unclear why you've reciprocated the coefficients.

Comment: Use $\frac{1}{{1 + w}} = 1 - w + w^2  + \mathcal{O}(w^3 )$ with $w = \frac{1}{{12 \cdot 2k}} + \frac{1}{{288 \cdot 4k^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{k^3 }}} \right)
$. Are trying to derive the asymptotics for the reciprocal of the central binomials $\binom{2k}{k}$? We have better ways to determine the full expansion.

Comment: I'm trying to evaluate $f(n)=\frac{(n-2)!!}{(n-3)!!}$ for n=2k by using stirling aproximation

Comment: Write it like $\sqrt \pi  \frac{{\Gamma (k)}}{{\Gamma \left( {k - \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}$ and use http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13 or http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E14

Comment: Let me say, that formally the title poses a different problem than the body of the question. In general, the answer to the title is that you cannot divide with big-$O$: when in denominator you have $O(f)$, even with $f \gt 0$, then necessary identically zero function belongs to $O(f)$, which makes impossible division. I am writing this as a comment, because from the body of the question and from the other comments I see that you are interested in your specific task and not the general question that is in the title. Although, probably, it would still be better to clarify the title.

Comment: I'm only intrested in how wolfram produces this result or any different correct/ how to evaluate $\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{12k}+\frac{1}{288k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\right)^2}{1+\frac{1}{12\cdot 2k}+\frac{1}{288\cdot 4k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)}$ by something with Big O in simplier form.

Comment: @SimonWieniawski Does my very first comment involving $w$ answer your question?

Comment: @Gary I got Wolfram result on my paper now. Thanks for your suggestion and help!